# How to introduce content in existing tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would know if it's possible to introduce a new element inside an existing tab in Boostrap 4

```
 <div id="productsTabs" style="overflow: auto;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-column flex-sm-row" role="tablist"  id="myTab">
       <li class="nav-item"><?php echo '<a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active">' . OSCOM::getDef('tab_general') . '</a>'; ?></a></li>
       <li class="nav-item"><?php echo '<a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">' . OSCOM::getDef('tab_stock'); ?></a></li>
      </ul>
     </ul>
    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="tab-content">

          <div class="tab-content active" id="red">
            <h1>Red</h1>
            <p>red red red red red red</p> 
          </div>
          <div class="tab-content" id="orange">
            <h1>Orange</h1>
            <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-content" id="blue">
            <h1>Blue</h1>
            <p>Blue Blue Blue Blue</p>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now in this tab I want to override by a new element

```
          <div class="tab-content" id="orange">
            <h1>Orange</h1>
            <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>

            <h3>Brown</h3>
            <p>Brown Brown Brown</p>
          </div>
```

Do you know how to make this or do you know a script make this ?

Thank you

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append

Comment: Take a look at  [jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)

Comment: When you say override by a new element, do you want to REPLACE the Orange header with the Brown header or Add the Brown header beneath the Orange header?

Comment: Add the Brown header beneath the Orange header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an element to a page, you can use append from jQuery.

> The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the first child, use .prepend()).

[jQuery Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('#orange').append(
    '<h3>Brown</h3>' + 
    '<p>Brown Brown Brown</p>'
)
```

### Update: javascript alternative

If you have an aversion to jQuery, javascript also provides an append function called appendChild().

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.

[javascript Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```
var orngTab = document.querySelector("#orange");
var brwnHead = document.createElement("h3");
var brwnPar = document.createElement("p");

brwnHead.innerHTML = "Brown";
brwnPar.innerHTML = "Brown Brown Brown";

orngTab.appendChild(brwnHead);
orngTab.appendChild(brwnPar);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there are other elements inside the `orange` tab too and you want to append the new header **just after** the orange one, it may be better to use `after` (http://api.jquery.com/after) like this:

```
$('#orange h1').after(
    '<h3>Brown</h3>' + 
    '<p>Brown Brown Brown</p>'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [append()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) to append html elements, with [has()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_has.asp) and [not()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp) to append only if the element doesn't exists.

```js
$('#append').on('click', () => {
        $('#orange').not(':has(h3)').append('<h3>Brown</h3><p>Brown Brown Brown</p>');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="productsTabs" style="overflow: auto;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-column flex-sm-row" role="tablist"  id="myTab">
        <li class="nav-item">removed PHP code</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Removed PHP code</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab-content">

            <div class="tab-content active" id="red">
                <h1>Red</h1>
                <p>red red red red red red</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content" id="orange">
                <h1>Orange</h1>
                <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content" id="blue">
                <h1>Blue</h1>
                <p>Blue Blue Blue Blue</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="append">Append Brown</button>
```